# DataSource.Read prevents BindTo for Kendo ComboBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

For some reason, my `MVC` `Kendo ComboBox` doesn't bind to the underlying data-set when I set a `READ ACTION` in the `DATA SOURCE`.

**WHAT AM I TRYING TO DO?**

- When the View Models list has records...bind to the list
- When the user types-in a value...make an Ajax call...and bind to the result

**The Issue**
Apparently, when you configure both a `BindTo` & `DataSource.Read Action` the binding is ignored.

**How do I know this?**

- When I put a break-point in the READ ACTION & look at the client-side `dataSource._data` collection...it is empty
- When I comment-out the READ...the binding works...but doing that would require me to configure the READ by-hand

**THIS MARKUP IS A FAIL:**
Because...

- Although, the READ occurs immediately (which is problematic on its' own)
- The BIND is ignored

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.Entity.PrimaryCircuitConnectId)
      .Placeholder("Enter a Circuit Path...")
      .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.PrimaryCircuitConnectDetails, "CircuitConnectId", "CircuitConnectValue"))
      .MinLength(4)
      .Filter("startswith")
      .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("find", "CircuitConnectDetail", new { area = "" })))
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" }))
```

**THIS MARKUP IS A FAIL:**
Because...

- The READ would have to be created client side (by-hand)
- Although, the BIND is honored

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.Entity.PrimaryCircuitConnectId)
      .Placeholder("Enter a Circuit Path...")
      .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.PrimaryCircuitConnectDetails, "CircuitConnectId", "CircuitConnectValue"))
      .MinLength(4)
      .Filter("startswith")
      //.DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("find", "CircuitConnectDetail", new { area = "" })))
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" }))
```

**YES, THERE ARE RECORDS:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed BindTo and DataSource options are dedicated for different bindings - BindTo should be used for local data and the DataSoruce for remote data as it is described in this [documentation article](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/combobox/overview#model-binding). It is currently not recommended to use them both in one scenario.

Comment: Yeah...I missed that :-)